# How to render ASCII math in ng-repeat Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Hi i am getting input in ASCII Math format, when i directly put inside any div its rendering perfectly.

```
<script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=AM_HTMLorMML"></script>

<p>The area of a triangle with base `b` and height `h` is `1/2 bh`. The area of a circle with radius `r` is `pi r^2`.</p>
```

[sample output Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpqV0.jpg)

Here i am storing the user input in sql server in back end with c# and passing it to angular UI. While reading values using ng-repeat it is not rendering, it displays as it was stored.

```
 <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
                                <tr ng-repeat="detail in $data">
                                    <td data-title="'S.No'">{{$index+1}}</td>
                                    <td data-title="'Q.No'" data-sortable="'QNo'">{{detail.QNo}}</td>
                                    <td data-title="'Question'" data-sortable="'Question'">{{detail.Question}}</td> <!-- ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(detail.Question)"-->
                                    <td data-title="'Option1'" data-sortable="'Option1'">{{detail.Option1}}</td></tr></table>
```

[Actual output i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGNmg.jpg)

Comment: There are a couple of examples of how to integrate MathJax with Angular using a directive [here](http://jsfiddle.net/spicyj/YpqVp/) and [here](https://github.com/ViktorQvarfordt/AngularJS-MathJax-Directive).

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.